# How to disable background in JQueryUI - Modal Form?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have just started working in jQuery and ASP.NET MVC. I want the same modal form mentioned in the example of JQuery site - http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form

```
$("#divSchedule").dialog({ 
                          autoOpen: false,
                          show: "slide", 
                          modal: true   
                         });
$("#btn").click(function () {
    $("#divSchedule").dialog("open"); 
    return false;
});
```

Dialog appears on the page but user can click on any of the background controls. Can you please suggest something to disable(blur) the background? Is it something to do with CSS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you made a mess of your dialog definition, try this http://jsfiddle.net/tctc2/1/

Comment: Thanks bud.. I guess, I need to learn "on the fly" coding style for JQ rather than more conventional structured way...

Comment: There's just no need for overdoing it. In your example you declared variable dialogOptions twice, and then tried to parametrize your dialog twice.

Comment: Thats true... grown in age of late 2002 asp.net arena where JS had to be ignored and every JS should be written with lots of comments and easy to read... JQ will be paradigm shift for me

Answer (score 4):

The quick answer for his question is:
use `modal: true` in order to

1. make background darker
2. disable any interaction with background functionality